# Min SQL user privilege to query sys.objects and sys.partitions in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I would like to have SQL user which can perform following SQL, but not able to read contents of other schemas.

What is best way to implement?

```
SELECT (Schema_name(A.schema_id) + '.' + A.NAME ) AS TableName,
       Sum(B.rows) AS RecordCount
FROM sys.objects A
         INNER JOIN sys.partitions B
                 ON A.object_id = B.object_id
WHERE A.type = 'U'
GROUP BY A.schema_id, A.NAME
```

Comment: What do you mean by not able to read contents of other schemas, as in objects on the `dbo` schema?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Create a stored procedure that runs that SQL. Then grant the user execute permissions on that single stored procedure.

Comment: `sys.objects` is already filtered to objects the user has (some) permission on, so the best way to prevent them from seeing anything in other schemas is to ensure they have no permission on objects in those schemas (or the schemas themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For columns, there is a row for every permission that is different from the corresponding object-level permission. If the column permission is the same as the corresponding object permission, there is no row for it and the permission applied is that of the object.

> Note: Column-level permissions override object-level permissions on
> the same entity.

Specifies a permission that can be granted on a schema. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

In rare circumstances, combining ALTER and REFERENCE rights may allow the grantee to access data or perform prohibited operations. For instance, a user with ALTER access on a table and REFERENCE permission on a function can build and execute a calculated column over a function. The user must also have SELECT permission on the calculated column in this situation.